# python twisted server with C# client

Tags: c#, python, .net, unity-container, twisted

i have a python twisted tcp server which i transfer data with this code :

```
self.transport.write("true")
```

it transfers the string "true".

and i plan to get it in my C# client with this code :

```
byte[] rba = new byte[tcpclnt.ReceiveBufferSize];
stm.Read (rba, 0, (int)tcpclnt.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

i both tried UTF8 and Default(ASCII) encode to convert it to string :

```
string returndata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (rba);
```

and

```
string returndata = Encoding.Default.GetString (rba);
```

and tried to do this :

```
if ( returndata == "true" ) 
    do something
```

but it doesn't equal returndata to "true" and i have no idea why ?

can anyone help me to understand it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Please show us what those attempts _did_ return.  Also, printing the ASCII codes of the bytes you got would be helpful.

Comment: which attemp u mean ? but i can tell u when i print returndata in console it shows me "true" ( both ascii and utf8 ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] rba = new byte[tcpclnt.ReceiveBufferSize];
var len=stm.Read (rba, 0, (int)tcpclnt.ReceiveBufferSize);
string returndata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (rba,len);
```

You are decoding the entire buffer rather than just the 4 bytes you got.  `stm.Read` should return 4, which you can then use in the `GetString` to tell it to stop after 4.

Alternatively, you can probably do this too:

```
var returndata = stm.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: yeah problem was i needed the 4 bytes so i changed tcpclnt.ReceiveBufferSize to 4.